# ActiveMQ datastore for cluster setup

Tags: activemq-classic

We have been using ActiveMQ version 5.16.0 broker with single instances in production. Now we are planning to use cluster of AMQ brokers for HA and load distribution with consistency in message data.  Currently we are using only one queue

HA can be achieved using failover but do we need to use the same datastore or it can be separated? If I use different instances for AMQ brokers then how to setup a common datastore.

Please guide me how to setup datastore for HA and load distribution

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: This is a fairly complicated question. What _exactly_ needs to be highly available? Is it just a matter of keeping the overall service up, or do you need total consistency in message data? Do you use features like message groups, that require consistency in message ordering? Do you have the infrastructure to provide a robust, shared message store, if the application seems to require one?

Comment: Hi @KevinBoone, I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ActiveMQ servers clustered together can provide HA in a couple ways:

1. Scale message flow by using compute resources across multiple broker nodes
2. Maintain message flow during single node planned or unplanned outage of a broker node
3. Share data store in the event of ActiveMQ process failure.

Network of brokers solve #1 and #2. A standard 3-node cluster will give you excellent performance and ability to scale the number of producers and consumers, along with splitting the full flow across 3-nodes to provide increased capacity.

Solving for #3 is complicated-- in all messaging products. Brokers are always working to be completely empty-- so clustering the data store of a single-broker becomes an anti-pattern of sorts. Many times, relying on RAID disk with a single broker node will provide higher reliability than adding NFSv4, GFSv2, or JDBC and using shared-store.

That being said, if you must use a shared store-- follow best practices and use GFSv2 or NFSv4. JDBC is much slower and requires significant DB maintenance to keep running efficiently.

Note: [@Kevin Boone]'s note about CIFS/SMB is incorrect and CIFS/SMB should not be used. Otherwise, his responses are solid.

Comment: A naive implementation with JDBC will be slower, for sure. However, I've seen installations that manage to get pretty good throughput with JDBC. It requires some scary database tuning, however. My experience is that sites that already have a substantial investment in Oracle, for example, and have the expertise to tune and manage it, often want to use it with their message brokers. Databases seem to handle situatiuons where there are stagnant messages a lot better than, e.g., KahaDB does.

Comment: Also, while using a single broker with RAID disks might protect the message data against a disk failure, obviously it won't protect clients against a broker failure. That may, or may not, be a problem, depending on the business needs.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure ActiveMQ so that instances share a message store, or so they have separate message stores. If they share a message store, then (essentially) the brokers will automatically form a master-slave configuration, such that only one broker (at a time) will accept connections from clients, and only one broker will update the store. Clients need to identify both brokers in their connection URIs, and will connect to whichever broker happens to be master.

With a shared message store like this, locks in the message store coordinate the master-slave assignment, which makes the choice of message store critical. Stores can be shared filesystems, or shared databases. Only a few shared filesystem implementations work properly -- anything based on NFS 4.x should work. CIFS/SMB stores *can* work, but there's so much variation between providers that it's hard to be sure. NFS v3 *doesn't* work, however well-implemented, because the locking semantics are inappropriate. In any case, the store needs to be robust, or replicated, or both, because the whole broker cluster depends on it. No store, no brokers.

In my experience, it's easier to get good throughput from a shared file store than a shared database although, of course, there are many factors to consider. Poor network connectivity will make it hard to get good throughput with *any* kind of shared store (or any kind of cluster, for that matter).

When using individual message stores, it's typical to put the brokers into some kind of mesh, with 'network connectors' to pass messages from one broker to another. Both brokers will accept connections from clients (there is no master), and the network connections will deal with the situation where messages are sent to one broker, but need to be consumed from another.

Clients' don't necessarily need to specify all brokers in their connection URIs, but generally will, in case one of the brokers is down.

A mesh is generally easier to set up, and (broadly speaking) can handle more client load, than a master-slave with shared filestore. However, (a) losing a broker amounts to losing any messages that were associated with it (until the broker can be restored) and (b) the mesh interferes with messaging patterns like message grouping and exclusive consumers.

There's really no hard-and-fast rule to determine which configuration to use. Many installers who already have some sort of shared store infrastructure (a decent relational database, or a clustered NFS, for example) will tend to want to use it. The rise in cloud deployments has had the effect that mesh operation with no shared store has become (I think) a lot more popular, because it's so symmetric.

There's more -- a lot more -- that could be said here. As a broad question, I suspect the OP is a bit out-of-scope for SO. You'll probably get more traction if you break your question up into smaller, more focused, parts.

Comment: CIFS/SMB *cannot* work. Its locking mechanism is incorrect

Comment: Nevertheless, it does. I've seen it working in a number of substantial installations. CIFS itself supports locking modes that do work with ActiveMQ; the problem is in the way that filesystem drivers interact with locks. I certainly wouldn't _recommend_ CIFS with ActiveMQ, however.

Comment: Using CIFS/SMB will practically guarantee you get both brokers thinking they are active at one point and corrupting the data store.

Comment: curiously, what CIFS/SMB service have you seen that work successfully? I've never seen success on Win64, and wonder that there maybe enhancements in Samba that may have better results.

Comment: The installations that I've seen working -- and this is just my particular experience of  few sites -- have been based on proprietary NAS-type products that have CIFS support, with brokers on Linux. These products generally support other protocols as well, and it's not entirely clear to me why somebody would choose CIFS as a file-sharing protocol for Linux clients. Conceivably their support for CIFS is more robust than their support for NFS -- I really don't know. The administrators of these sites have been keen to continue using CIFS, however.